# I got base64 [object file], how to convert it to correct base64 file?

Tags: javascript, base64

I got base64 `[object file]`, how to convert it to the correct base64 file?

I used DevExtreme Filemanager plugin, but when I upload the file and want to got base64 code, it always got `W29iamVjdCBGaWxlXQ==`

```
console.log(btoa(fileData));
```

when I used console.log(fileData);

```
File {name: "202107.xlsx", lastModified: 1625651854258, lastModifiedDate: Wed Jul 07 2021 17:57:34 , webkitRelativePath: "", size: 9876, …}
lastModified: 1625651854258
lastModifiedDate: Wed Jul 07 2021 17:57:34  {}
name: "202107.xlsx"
size: 9876
type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

and my code is below, I tried to used it, but it want run this code "console.log(reader.result);" , I don't know what happen?

```
function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileData);
  reader.onload = function () {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };
console.log(window.btoa(fileData));
}
```

or

```
if (fileData.length > 0) {
    getBase64(fileData[0]);
  }
function getBase64(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileData[0]);
  reader.onload = function () {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };

  console.log(window.btoa(fileData));
}
```

It all didn't run `console.log(reader.result);`

How should I do it then can get base64 code?

Comment: Can you edit your post to focus on the one question you want to ask? Because you're already showing using `.readAsDataURL`, so as long as you follow [the docs for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL#javascript), that'll work just fine.

Comment: Set `onload` before you call `readAsDataURL`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'd tried that methods, but it isn't working for me, and I not just upload image, I will upload .pdf, docx, .xlsx etc. But I always cannot get base64 format.

Comment: @AvinashThakur I'd changed it. But still cannot working.  reader.onload = function () {
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileData[0]);
    console.log(reader.result);
  };

console.log(reader.result);  <<<< this line still not work

Comment: this is my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/hierarchical-js-structure-devextreme-file-manager-forked-45yc5?file=/App.vue

Comment: You tried what? That link literally shows you 100% certified working code, are you saying that code doesn't work for you? Because it's hard to tell what you're asking at the moment in your post: please update it to explain what you wanted to do, then what code you wrote to do that, then how that code is misbehaving (e.g. given what input, what is it's output/behaviour, and how does that differ from what you expected), and what you already did in terms of debugging.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans He hasn't included this file reader in that code. However, It worked easily for me when I added FileReader and from the question, it looks like he is treating fileData like an array.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of [uploadFileChunk](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxFileManager/File_System_Providers/Custom/Configuration/#uploadFileChunk)

> ### uploadFileChunk
>
> A function that uploads a file in chunks.
>
> Type: [Function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)
>
> Function parameters:
>
> file: [File](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file)
> The file that is being uploaded.
>
> uploadInfo: [UploadInfo](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Object_Structures/UploadInfo/)
> Information about the file upload session.
>
> destinationDirectory: [FileSystemItem](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Object_Structures/FileSystemItem/)
> The directory where a file system item is uploaded to.
>
> Return Value: Promise (jQuery or native) | any
> A Promise that is resolved after the file system item is uploaded. It is a > native Promise or a jQuery.Promise when you use jQuery.

Hence, you don't have to use `fileData[0]`.

Following code worked in your `uploadFileChunk` function

```js
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = () => {
    console.log(fr.result, fr)
  }
  fr.readAsDataURL(fileData);
```

Complete function:

```js
function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
  console.log('is array: ', Array.isArray(fileData))
  console.log('is File: ', (fileData instanceof File))
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = () => {
    console.log(fr.result)
  }
  fr.readAsDataURL(fileData);
  // get a file destination directory when uploading here
  return objectProvider.uploadFileChunk(
    fileData,
    uploadInfo,
    destinationDirectory
  );
}
```